# Scrollbar is permanently determining the size of my nav tag

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how else to describe this: When a scroll bar appears and I scroll to the right due to overflow, my `nav` tag is resized to a shorter field. In any case, pictures are better:

[image: Without Scrollbar]

[image: With Scrollbar]

In the second image, it is obvious that the field has shortened in length. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Style2.css"/>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/menu_dropdown.js"></script>

  <nav class="clearfix">  
    <ul class="clearfix">  
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Territory</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Publishers</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Special Campaign</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>    
</ul>  
<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
```

The `CSS`:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../Images/bg.jpg)
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {  
  height: 40px;  
  width: 100%;  
  background: #455868;  
  font-size: 11pt;  
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;  
  font-weight: bold;  
  position: relative;  
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;  
}  
nav ul {  
  padding: 0;  
  margin: 0 auto;  
  width: 900px;  
  height: 40px;  
}  

nav li {  
  display: inline;  
  float: left;  
}  

.clearfix:before,  
.clearfix:after {  
  content: " ";  
  display: table;  
}  
.clearfix:after {  
  clear: both;  
}  
.clearfix {  
  *zoom: 1;  
}  

nav a {  
  color: #fff;  
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 150px;  
  text-align: center;  
  text-decoration: none;  
  line-height: 40px;  
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;  
}  

nav li a {  
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;  
  box-sizing:border-box;  
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  
}  
nav li:last-child a {  
  border-right: 0;  
}  

nav a:hover, nav a:active {  
  background-color: #8c99a4;  
}  

nav a#pull {  
  display: none;  
}  

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
nav {   
    height: auto;  
}  
nav ul {  
    width: 100%;  
    display: block;  
    height: auto;  
}  
nav li {  
    width: 50%;  
    float: left;  
    position: relative;  
}  
nav li a {  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;  
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;  
}  
nav a {  
    text-align: left;  
    width: 100%;  
    text-indent: 25px;  
}  
}  

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {  
nav {  
    border-bottom: 0;  
}  
nav ul {  
    display: none;  
    height: auto;  
}  
   nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
nav a#pull:after {
    content:"";
    background: url(../Images/nav-icon.png) no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
} 
}  

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {  
nav li {  
    display: block;  
    float: none;  
    width: 100%;  
}  
nav li a {  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;  
}  
}
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav width is 100%! it's only going to be 100% width of the body. If you scroll to the right, your nav doesn't get any bigger. The text is just overflowing out of it. I'd suggest setting the backgrounds of each nav item to a solid color.

EDIT: an odd fix: Change your `width: 100%` from the nav to `min-width: 100%`. That (and the fact that nav is a block element) is what is limiting the width. In order to make sure it flows to the right, put `display: inline-block` in its place.

Comment: Uh, that doesn't quite work. It certainly flows to the right, but it is only long enough to hold the text. On my monitor, I'm essentially left with half a page of pure background at the top.

Comment: Ah. yeah. forgot about `min-width: 100%`;

Comment: Beautiful! So does adding `min-width: 100%` guarantee that the field will span the entire body?

Comment: `min-width` guarantees that your nav will span at least the body. `display: inline-block` guarantees that your nav will span its own contents. So, yes. =)

Answer (score 1):

yeah this is an annoying.

the problem with setting a width to 100% is that zooming or different screen sizes can render it differently depending on other css rules.

you should set a `min-width` to whatever you expect the usual width to be.

for me a `min-width:960px`  usually does the trick but it looks like your using a 900px value.

so add `min-width:900px` to your nav {} style rules.  or whatever width youre using.

```
nav {  
  height: 40px;  
  width: 100%;  
  background: #455868;  
  font-size: 11pt;  
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;  
  font-weight: bold;  
  position: relative;  
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
  min-width:900px;
}
```

Comment: CSS is really not intuitive to me. I prefer to work on the server-side with PHP. Oh well, so would I need to set a min-width within each media query? It works fine in a standard "desktop" mode, but when it comes to tablets it encounters this issue.

Comment: That somewhat works. It fixes the issue of a diminishing field, but it interferes with the media queries.

Comment: @Mlagma you should just need to add similiar rules for each media query size.  You can even unset the min-width if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Find your `nav a` css style and replace this css and done.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/bC63a/

## NEW

```
nav a {  
  color: #fff;  
  background: #455868;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744; 
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 150px;  
  text-align: center;  
  text-decoration: none;  
  line-height: 40px;  
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;  
}
```

## OLD

```
nav a {  
  color: #fff;  
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 150px;  
  text-align: center;  
  text-decoration: none;  
  line-height: 40px;  
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;  
}
```